# how to show strings with tags (<>) correctly in the interface

Tags: sql, function, tags, escaping, concatenation

My string inside a tag does not show up because I need to concatenate it, how do I do so?

```js
success: function (response) {
    var tbody = "";
    $.each(response.all_legends, function (key, legend) {
        tbody += '<tr>'+
                    '<td>'+'<AGE>'+'</td>'+
                    '<td>'+legend.text+'</td>'+
                '</tr>';
        });
    $('#legend-list tbody').html(tbody)
}
```

I tried adding additional `+` and quotations but the tag still does not show up

**CLARIFICATIONS:**

`legend.text` works since it is a regular string. its the `<AGE>` tag that does not show up. I tried to `console.log` the tables, it shows up normally in the console but does not appear in the

**UPDATE:**

Database:

[image: 1]

Interface:

[image: 2]

For Clarification, because the first example was a test to fix the tags. I need to mention further that the string has the tags so I cannot just simple encase it in some kind of escape like `&lt;AGE&gt`

Here is what I tried:

```
'<td><a href="" onclick="appendMessageText(this)" class="blue-1">'+escape(legend.value)+'</a></td>'+
```

I can retrieve the database column using a loop with `legend.value` (1st screenshot).
adding the escape turns the tags into its entities (2nd screenshot).
How do I fix up the strings with tags?

Comment: So, your problem is that `legend.text` is not showing anything ? If so, I think you have to do `response.data.all_legends` instead of `response.all_legends`. If that does not work, can you do `console.log(response)` before `$.each` and show as an image ? There should be a `data` or similar.

Comment: guess i need to clarify it, `legend.text` works since it is a regular string. its the `<AGE>` tag that does not show up. I tried to console.log the tables, it shows up normally in the console but does not appear in the UI.

Comment: That is happening because `<AGE>` is been inserted literally like a normal HTML tag... you have to "escape" it. Try `&lt;AGE&gt;` instead of `<AGE>`. `&lt;` and `&gt;` are just HTML entities.

Comment: actually opened a new question for this since my string has the tags:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69158840/showing-tags-in-escape-from-a-database-column-containing-strings-with-tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think make sense this code. If '<' and '>' chars are at the beginning and at the end, this code help you

```
const editText = (text) => `<a><</a><a>${text.replace('<','').replace('>','')}</a><a>></a>`;
 
success: function (response) {
var tbody = "";
$.each(response.all_legends, function (key, legend) {
    tbody += '<tr>'+
                '<td>'+editText(legend.value)+'</td>'+
                '<td>'+legend.text+'</td>'+
            '</tr>';
    });
$('#legend-list tbody').html(tbody)
```

}