# showing tags in escape() from a database column containing strings with tags

Tags: javascript, sql, function, escaping, each

I have this for each, the `legend.value` is a column in my table where all strings are tags

```
            $.each(response.all_legends, function (key, legend) {
            tbody+='<tr>'+
                        '<td><a href="" onclick="appendMessageText(this)" class="blue-1">'+escape(legend.value)+'</a></td>'+
                        '<td>'+legend.text+'</td>'+
                    '</tr>';
            });
```

[image: 1]

my problem is that when I encased it inside `escape()` the tags turn into their entities, how do I fix the UI issue?

[image: 2]

Comment: Try using [`template string`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: I solved this problem
[answered for last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69100160/how-to-show-strings-with-tags-correctly-in-the-interface?answertab=votes#tab-top)